# POP3 клиент и кириллица

Tags: pop3, perl

Написал `POP3` клиент на перле. Оттестировал, получил почту в иероглифах, не удивился. Но как это исправить? Желательно без использования каких-либо модулей.

UPD: В общем письмо доставляется в `utf-8`. Декодировать можно с помощью функции `decode` или `from_to` из модуля `Encode`. Вопрос остался один, какая кодировка-то нужна, чтоб в консоли кирилица выводилась?

Comment: там ниже спросили - консоль под какую ОС?

Answer (score 1):

Core модуль Encode поможет перевести из одной кодировки в другую.

- В виндоус - использовать метод `Win32::Console->InputCP()`
- В линуксах сейчас `utf8` (т.е. use utf8 использовать). Или `use locale`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Понять в какой кодировке пришла почта и в какую нужно преобразовать.
2. Пропустить принятый текст через `iconv` утилиту .

Answer (score 0):

У меня, например, так работает:

```
use Convert::Cyrillic;

use MIME::EncWords qw(:all);

...
```

`charset` - глобальная переменная. Получена из `header`'a письма - из строки `Charset=...`

```
sub decodeparam{

        my $src = shift(); # текст письма передается сюда

if($src =~ /\=\?([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)\?[BQbq]\?/i){  # =?utf-8?Q??=

$src = decode_mimewords($src);

if ($1 =~ /koi/i){$src = Convert::Cyrillic::cstocs('KOI8', 'WIN', $src);}

if ($1 =~ /iso/i){$src = Convert::Cyrillic::cstocs('ISO', 'WIN', $src);}

if ($1 =~ /utf/i){$src = Convert::Cyrillic::cstocs('UTF8', 'WIN', $src);}

    }

else{

if ($charset =~ /koi/i){$src = Convert::Cyrillic::cstocs('KOI8', 'WIN', $src);}

if ($charset =~ /iso/i){$src = Convert::Cyrillic::cstocs('ISO', 'WIN', $src);}

if ($charset =~ /utf/i){$src = Convert::Cyrillic::cstocs('UTF8', 'WIN', $src);}

    }

        return $src;

};
```

Кодировку определяет из двух источников.

Работает больше года без ошибок. Правда, в основном, конечно, почта приходит из яндекса, гмейла, мейла и других больших почтовиков. А у них, в основном, все по правилам.

Answer (score -1):

А вы уверены, что само письмо составлено правильно, указаны верные кодировки в хиадерах и текст соответствует указанной кодировке?

Answer (score -1):

1. Примеры того, что тебе выводится.
2. Консоль то где: в винде, линуксе? Локаль какая?
3. Про внутреннее представление юникода в perl знаем?
4. Сам скрипт в юникоде написан, utf8?